# TableView adding a cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm doing a project in which I have a TableView in which I have different Rows/Cell and in each cell there is a add button. What I need to do is on clicking the add button the new row should add below the row in which I clicked the button, means I have to add a cell to the next of the selected button on the row.and also a user can enter  a text on the new row. Please tell me how to do this . As I'm new in iPhone development. I will be very thankful ....

Here is a click button function in which I want to perform an action to add new cell.

```
- (IBAction)AddButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [_choices insertObject:@"avav" atIndex:[_choices count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"here");

}
```

Comment: This will help you start http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: i have already seen that i am not able to integrate it onmy project

Comment: You have textfeild in all cells?

Comment: You should have a look at `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` once your array and your table is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Use this delegate method to add a new row below the selected row. And use custom cell to have a text field on it...

```
     rowCount ++;//Here rowcount refers the no. of rows in the table. 
     selectedIndexPath = indexPath;//Assign the selected indexpath for creating custom cell on it. 
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];//Indexpath refers the currently selected/targeted cell.
```

In cellforRowAtIndexPath use like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if((selectedIndexPath) && (indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath.row) && (indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath.section))
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
        NewCell *cell = (NewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSString *customeCellName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NewCell class]];

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customeCellName owner:self options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell =  (NewCell *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
    }
}
```

OutPut will be like this
[image]

need  to customize as per your requirement.

Comment: @durgaprasad no i have add button and i can add row on button click and in that new row user can enter text.

Comment: in else part i am doing this

Answer (score 0):

I consider you have textfeild in all cells. In AddButtonAction function save index of row. While creating cells make selected cell textfeild firstresponder. Once user enter data save it in array and again reload. Just keep track of selectedIndex properly.
Ifeel this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you add button to cell by `addSubview` method, simply you can get indexPath with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)AddButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[button superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Adding methods comes here...
}
```

If you are using some `addSubview` levels, you should use same `superview` methods inverse to access the UITableViewCell level. If using custom cells, replace your custom cell classname with UITableViewCell in the above code.

For adding cells, take a look at [WWDC 2011 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), "UITableView Changes, Tips & Tricks" video. It shows some nice and useful methods to insert, delete and reload new rows/sections between other rows/sections like `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method. Or see [Apple Documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a).